# Xamarin forms page doesn't load until async call is done

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to open a new page which shows a list that is populated with data from the server. The call to get the data from the server is done using an async function that is called from OnAppearing method. However, even though the method is async, my UI page is not shown until the call is done. How can I fix that or what is the best practice to make this call?

This is my XAML code for the page:

```
<StackLayout>
  <Label
    x:Name="NoPostsMessage"
    Text="You have not created any posts yet :("
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

  <ListView
    x:Name="PostList"
    SelectionMode="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextCell Text="{Binding Text}" Detail="{Binding Detail}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

This is my C# code:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
  base.OnAppearing();

  GetContributions();
}

async private void GetContributions()
{
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

  HttpResponseMessage response = await client
    .GetAsync
    (
      "websiteURL.com"
    );

  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
    APIResponse data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIResponse>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    if (data.ResponseCode == 1)
    {
      string payloadData = data.Data.ToString();
      List<TextCell> userPosts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TextCell>>(payloadData);

      if (userPosts.Count == 0)
      {
        NoPostsMessage.IsVisible = true;
        PostList.IsVisible = false;
      }
      else
      {
        NoPostsMessage.IsVisible = false;
        PostList.IsVisible = true;

        ReportsList.ItemsSource = userPosts;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      await DisplayAlert("Error", data.ErrorMessage, "OK");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    await DisplayAlert("Error", "An error has occurred, please try again later", "OK");
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `.Result` in a `async` method?

Comment: @Cheesebaron, Thanks for pointing that out. I forgot to change that when I changed the method to async. I'll replace it with await

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you do not use `await`, the `async` call will block the UI

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
  base.OnAppearing();

  await GetContributions();
}
```